# Spring-Boot 0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and customer Json MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Has anyone working with Spring-Boot figured out how to override the default Jackson ObjectMapper that is automatically configured? I have tried to instantiate both the ObjectMapper as a bean and within a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter also as a been. But with no success...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Spring handles HTTP `@ResponseBody` using the `HttpMessageConverter` abstraction, so it's there that you would have to add customizations. Normally you would add a `@Bean` extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override the `configureMessageConverters()` method.

Adding a `@Bean` of type `ObjectMapper` sounds like a neat way to do this for a Spring Boot application, so you could provide that feature in a pull request if you like.